# Почему при уменьшении окна браузера @media не меняет размер блока и цвета текстов?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries

```css
.container {width: 300px; height: 300px; background: red;}
.firstCase { color: green;  }
.secondCase { color: red;    }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.container {height:100px; width: 100px; background: red;}
.firstCase { color: red;  }
.secondCase { color: green;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>

<p class="firstCase">max-width:940</p>
<p class="firstCase">square = 300x300</p><br><br>

<p class="secondCase">max-width:500</p>
<p class="secondCase">square = 100x100</p><br>
```

Не могу понять, почему когда я уменьшаю окно хрома, то `@media` не меняет размер квадрата и цвета текстов?

Comment: Код рабочий. Откройте окно на всю ширину и проверьте. Не совсем понятно тогда, в чём тут проблема?

Comment: В том, что у меня он почему-то не работает, хотя по синтаксису и тп все верно. Попробую куки сбросить, хотя я ctrl + f5 нажимал не раз..

Comment: viewport не забыли добавить?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev это как?

Comment: Сбросил куки. Ничего не изменилось... Может дело в браузере или мне есть смысл дополнить код выше, чтобы дом структура была полностью видна от начала до конца?

Comment: Добавьте мета тег между тегом head <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Заработало, спасибо. Без понятия в чем была проблема, может быть в кукис, но сразу не обновилось.. :\\\